# Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser> UserManager<TUser>.GetUserRoleStore() ASP.NET Core MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, roles, asp.net-core-identity

I have implemented `Identity` in `Asp.Net.Core MVC 3` because we already have database tables that we want to use. I get the error when calling the methods below and they are both happening in the `UserManager` in the same call to the method. When looking at the source code for this method it is because the Store variable is null. But I am not quite sure how to make sure it is not null. I have looked at various solutions online but none solve my problem.

My solution is working with the `SignInManager` for passwords but I can not get it to get passed the error for Roles.

**ConfigureServices** Method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{           
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    });
    services.AddDbContext<EntitiesModel>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration["Data:ConnectionStrings:XXXXXXXXXXXXX"]));
    services.AddIdentity<UserViewModel, UserRoleViewModel>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    services.AddTransient<IUserStore<UserViewModel>, UserStore>();
    services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<UserRoleViewModel>, RoleStore>();
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;             
        options.LoginPath = "/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
    });         
}
```

**UserStore** class

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<UserViewModel>, IUserPasswordStore<UserViewModel>, IUserEmailStore<UserViewModel>, IUserRoleStore<UserRoleViewModel>
{ 
....
```

**RoleStore** class

```
public class RoleStore : IRoleStore<UserRoleViewModel>,IUserRoleStore<UserRoleViewModel>
{
....
```

**UserViewModel** class

```
public class UserViewModel 
{
    [Key, Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(128)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(1024)]
    public string Password { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<UserRoleViewModel> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**UserRoleViewRoleModel** class

```
public class UserRoleViewModel 
{    
    [Key, Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required, ForeignKey(nameof(Role))]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual RoleViewModel Role { get; set; }
    public virtual UserViewModel User { get; set; }
}
```

**RoleViewModel** class

```
public class RoleViewModel 
{   
    [Key,Required]
    public int RoleId  { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public virtual  ICollection<UserRoleViewModel> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

**Calling Code**
//this works
var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, user.Password, true, false);
//this fails
var test = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Management");
//this fails
var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

**Error**

> NotSupportedException: Store does not implement IUserRoleStore.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.GetUserRoleStore()

Forgive me if the way I have structured this is not right but I am new to this coming from ASP.Net Web Forms

Comment: Your `UserViewModel ` should be inherited from `IdentityUser` and `RoleViewModel` should be inherited from `IdentityUserRole`, follow [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and [Custom storage providers for ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: @TaoZhou Thanks, I am still working on it. Have not got it to work yet.

Answer (score 8):

Not Sure but it seems you forgot to add Role in start up.cs file

```
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<UserViewModel>()
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>();
```

Please find below link for more reference. 
http://qaru.site/questions/16512353/store-does-not-implement-iuserrolestoretuser-aspnet-core-21-identity

Comment: Have you inherit IdentityUser to your usermodel? e.g UserViewModel: IdentityUser. try as per link i have shared with you.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer may be the correct one, but I am still working on it.

Comment: I have inherited the IdentityUser as per the link but I am still getting the error.

Comment: I have posted a bounty on the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702588/error-in-service-iuserstore-being-created-in-identity-asp-net-core-3-mvc and will put a bounty on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line below:

services.AddTransient, UserStore>();