# Error in Service IUserStore being created in Identity Asp.net core 3 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

**Update**

See Update below.

I have asked a [previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654400/store-does-not-implement-iuserrolestoretuser-usermanagertuser-getuserrolesto) very recently, but  I face an issue after implementing the suggested solutions from the following 2 places [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and [Custom storage providers for ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0). I am just not able to get the solution to work. I have implemented the extension of `IdentityUser` as recommended and the extension of `IdentityRole`.   I have implemented `IUserPasswordStore` and `IUserRoleStore` and `IUserStore` for `UserStore` and I have implemented `IRoleStore` for `RoleStore`. I have also implemented the new dbContext `ApplicationDbContext` which implements `IdentityDbContext`. There was an issue with this with the constructor not accepting a parameter so I implemented a new constructor. I am not sure if this is right.

However that appears to be irrelevant because I get the error in the Main method of Program.cs when calling

```
CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

And the error is massive. I have placed it at the end. Searching the parts of the error online does not provide any ideas as to what I am doing, and as I am new to ASP.NET Core 3 and Identity I am stumped.

Here is the code I have so far.

**ConfigureServices** method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<EntitiesModel>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration["Data:ConnectionStrings:XXXXDbConnection"]));
        services.AddIdentity<UserViewModel,RoleViewModel>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddRoles<RoleViewModel>(); ;
        services.AddTransient<IUserStore<UserViewModel>, UserStore>();
        services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<RoleViewModel>, RoleStore>();
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
        });
    }
```

**ApplicationDbContext** - these are all in the same namespace

```
public class IdentityDbContext
    : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public IdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class IdentityDbContext<TUser>
    : IdentityDbContext<TUser, IdentityRole, string>
    where TUser : IdentityUser
{
    public IdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

// Uses the built-in Identity types except with custom User and Role types
// The key type is defined by TKey
public class IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey> : IdentityDbContext<
    TUser, TRole, TKey, IdentityUserClaim<TKey>, IdentityUserRole<TKey>,
    IdentityUserLogin<TKey>, IdentityRoleClaim<TKey>, IdentityUserToken<TKey>>
    where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey>
    where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey>
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    private DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options;
    //private string nameOrConnectionString;

    public IdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    {
        this.options = options;
    }

}

public abstract class IdentityDbContext<
        TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserRole, TUserLogin, TRoleClaim, TUserToken>
    : IdentityUserContext<TUser, TKey>
    where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey>
    where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey>
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    where TUserRole : IdentityUserRole<TKey>
{

}
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<UserViewModel,RoleViewModel,int>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserViewModel>(b =>
        {               
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.Id)
                .IsRequired();
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserViewModel>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("T_CustomerContacts");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleViewModel>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("T_LoginRoles");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleViewModel>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("T_CustomerContactRole");
        });         
        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleViewModel>(b =>
        {
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
}
```

**UserViewModel**

```
public class UserViewModel : IdentityUser<int>
{
```

**UserRoleViewModel**

```
public class UserRoleViewModel : IdentityUserRole<int>
{
```

**RoleViewModel**

```
public class RoleViewModel : IdentityRole<int>
{
```

**RoleStore**

```
public class RoleStore : IRoleStore<RoleViewModel>
{
```

**UserStore**

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<UserViewModel>, IUserPasswordStore<UserViewModel>, IUserRoleStore<UserRoleViewModel>
{
```

I have to add that this is the final configuration I have tried. I have tried many combinations and solutions.
Part of the error is as follows

> An error occurred while starting the application.
>   AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.UserViewModel] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.UserViewModel,TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.RoleViewModel,TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.ApplicationDbContext,System.Int32]': Unable to resolve service for type 'TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.UserViewModel,TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.RoleViewModel,TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.ApplicationDbContext,System.Int32]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.RoleViewModel] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore`3[TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.RoleViewModel,TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.ApplicationDbContext,System.Int32]': Unable to resolve service for type 'TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore`3[TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.RoleViewModel,TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Models.ViewModel.Identity.ApplicationDbContext,System.Int32]'.)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)

**Update**

I am back to where I began with the previous question and but solved the above error by reversing the orders of the following

```
    services.AddTransient<IUserStore<UserViewModel>, UserStore>();
        services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<RoleViewModel>, TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Identity.RoleStore>();
        services.AddIdentity<UserViewModel,RoleViewModel>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddRoles<RoleViewModel>();
```

But as stated now I am getting [Store does not implement IUserRoleStore UserManager.GetUserRoleStore()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654400/store-does-not-implement-iuserrolestoretuser-usermanagertuser-getuserrolesto) error which has put me back to square one.

Comment: Have you try registering your services with scoped lifetime?         `services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<RoleViewModel>, TrussCorp.CustomerPortal.Identity.RoleStore>();`

Comment: @Kahbazi I have added this now and I am still getting the error Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser> UserManager<TUser>.GetUserRoleStore()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice to other Developers is if you can not find a similar problem on the internet, you are doing something silly and unique.

The solution was to change this

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<UserViewModel>, IUserPasswordStore<UserViewModel>, IUserRoleStore<UserRoleViewModel>
{
```

to this

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<UserViewModel>, IUserPasswordStore<UserViewModel>, IUserRoleStore<UserViewModel>
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try instead adding this in the top perhaps?

```
services.AddIdentity<UserViewModel,RoleViewModel>().AddUserStore<UserStore>().AddRoleStore<RoleStore>();
```